# Confusion with 대 for quoted speech (please correct my sentences!)

Tags: grammar

She said she'll come later
나중에 온대

She said she was late
늦었대

She said she wasn't feeling well so she won't be going to class tomorrow
얘가 아파서 내일에 학교에 안 간대

I said I'm eating

1. 먹는대
2. 먹는다고

He said he ate it but he didn't

1. 얘가 먹었대지만 안 먹었어
2. 얘가 먹었대는데 안 먹었어
3. 얘가 먹은 것이라고 했는데 안 먹었어

He said he was going to eat it but he didn't in the end
얘가 먹은대지만 결국 안 먹었어

Can I combine ~대 with 는데/지만?

Is there a difference between 데 and 대? For example instead of saying 온대 I say 온데.

Please give me some examples with ~대 that covers past, present and future tense if you can. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

> She said she'd come later 나중에 온대
>
> She said she was late 늦었대
>
> She said she wasn't feeling well so she won't be going to class tomorrow 얘가 아파서 내일에 학교에 안 간대

All correct.

> I said 'I am eating'
>
> 1. 먹는대
> 2. 먹는다고

I would say "**먹고 있다고** 했어" since it's in progressive tense. The person who said 'I am eating' is the first person so you can't use -대 in this case.

> He said he ate it but he didn't
>
> 1. 얘가 먹었대지만 안 먹었어
> 2. 얘가 먹었대는데 안 먹었어
> 3. 얘가 먹은 것이라고 했는데 안 먹었어

먹었대지만 and 먹었대는데 are informal but both are OK when spoken, I think. Or to make it clearer:

"얘가 **먹었다고 했**는데 / **먹었댔**는데, (사실은) 안 먹었어"

> He said he was going to eat it but he didn't in the end 얘가 먹은대지만 결국 안 먹었어

"얘가 **먹는댔지만** 결국 안 먹었어". 먹은대지만 doesn't make sense

> Can I combine ~대 with 는데/지만?

Yes. -대는데/-대지만 are spoken in everyday conversation but -다는데/-다지만 is the correct formal form.

> Is there a difference between 데 and 대? For example instead of saying 온대 I say 온데.

데 and 대 are totally different. 온대 is a shorthand for "온다고 해" while 온데 does not even make sense.

> Please give me some examples with ~대 that covers past, present and future tense if you can.

친구가 거기 갔대 (A friend of mine said he went there)

친구가 거기 가고 있대 (A friend of mine said he was going there)

친구가 거기 간대 (갈 거래) (A friend of mine said he would go there)

Answer (score 0):

1.기본적으로 ~대 는 남의 말을 전할때만 씁니다
그래서 [ 나는 말했다 '나는 먹는중' ]이란 말은
'~대'로 만들 수 없는 말입니다

basically ~대 use when you convey other people's talk
so [ i said 'i am eating' ] cannot be used

2.만약 [i said' i am eating'] 이라고 말하고 싶으면
'먹는 중이라고 말 했어' 가 자연스럽습니다

if you want to say [i said' i am eating']
'먹는 중이라고 말했어' will be good

3.[He said he was going to eat it but he didn't in the end
얘가 먹은대지만 결국 안 먹었어]

이 문장또한 어색합니다
'~대/는데' 는 '지만' 과 함께 쓰지 않습니다
'그가 먹을거라고 했는데 결국 안먹었어'
라고해야 자연스럽습니다.

This sentence is also little bit awkward
because '~대/는데' cannot combine with '~지만'
'그가 먹을거라고 했는데 결국 안먹었어'
will be good

have a nice day!